# Ray marching using depth Buffer

Tags: graphics, shader, raymarching

I'm trying to create some screen space effects such as SSR and Global ilumination. I've already noticed that it is donne using rayMarching and depth buffer.
I am familiar with rayMarching algorithm in context of unity and shadertoy  . However I'm not understating how does it work in depth buffer, how does rayMarching in depth buffers is donne? Can anyone show  me some minimal code on how to do it?

Comment: On Shadertoy, I found [a demo](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdycWy) of two-pass ray marching using a depth buffer (or "zbuffer").